# Regular expression issue. Find needed strings

Tags: .net, regex

Input string is

```
@"SomeCall(Resource.T(""String )))1""), ""String 2"", ""String 3"");"
```

I want to get only `"String 2"` and `"String 3"`, *but **not** `"String )))1"`.

I use this expression:

```
 (?<!Resource\.T)("(?:\.|[^\"])*")
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD.** Changed

```
(?<!Resource\.T)
```

to

```
(?<!Resource\.T\()
```

, but the result is

```
"), ", ", "
```

for now :)

Comment: Arbitrarily nested `()` - regex is not a great solution for that. Or do I understand the rules incorrectly?

Comment: Doesn't matter. This is simplified example, that also does not work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lookbehind isn't quite right, that's why it doesn't work. Change it to:

```
 (?<!Resource\.T\()
```

Right before the `"`, you have to look if there is no `Resource.T(` before, not just `Resource.T`.

**Edit:**
Ok, so to fix the problem, we'll try to see if there is a pair number of `"` after the match:

```
(?<!Resource\.T\()("(?:\.|[^\"])*")(?=(?:[^"]|"[^"]*")*$)
```

So, we check until the end of the string if there is an another `"` and if there is, make sure there's a second one.
I think that's the most general way (maybe not the best performance-oriented though).

Comment: Yep, you're right. I fixed and achieve "), ", ", " in result :) that is not the result I want to see))

Comment: Yup, quite normal considering your case, I'll try to give you a good enough solution, editing.

Comment: Looks like the solution :):) Thank you very much!

Comment: At least I cant make this doesn't work and all unit-tests work good! :) Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!Resource\.T)("(?:\.|[^\")])*")
```

Comment: If you add a `)` in the class, why bother keeping the lookbehind?

Answer (score 0):

As Loamhoof said, you need to add the "(" in the negative lookbehind. But then, as you saw, the first match is the end-quote of String 1 matched with the beginning quote of String 2. If you know the strings won't have commas in them, you could match by excluding commas:

```
(?<!Resource\.T\()("[^,"]*")
```

Comment: So.. I think this is bad solution. Becase string still can contain "," :( Actually it can be any string you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about this again, I think the real problem is that the "bad" Resource.T string must be consumed, so you shouldn't use a zero-width assertion. That's what threw off the beginning and ending quotes. If you enclose any Resource.T match in a non-capturing group, then you should only get back the others:

```
(?:Resource\.T\("[^"]*"\))|("[^"]*")
```

Answer (score 0):

How strict is the input format?
Is this ok?

`@"SomeCall\(Resource.T\(""[^"]*""\), ""([^"]*)"", ""([^"]*)""\);"`

If your input string ist always formatted like your example, there's no need to bother with a complex lookaround regex.
If it's not, of course, this won't work.